# Data count discrepancy

Tags: excel, match

I have two columns with different amount of values in them. Col A has 2789 values, col B has 201 values.

Using the function

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$2789,0)),"",A2)
```

in col C and dragging it down to C2789, I get the values that exist in both col A and col B. I select them, paste them into notepad or word (to get rid of the formulas), paste them back into Excel and remove all the blanks using Find & Select.

I repeat this for all the values that don't match in col B and col C using

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,$C$2:$C$140,0)),B2,"")
```

You would expect C and D together to have 201 data items, but I'm getting 207 in the status bar between those two.

Can anyone shed some light on this? All input is welcome.

Comment: First off, you don't need to copy to notepad or word to get rid of formulas. Copy, rightclick in Excel, then select Paste Special -> Values.

Comment: Also it appears you have duplicate values in one of your lists. Go to the Data Ribbon and select remove duplicates and it will delete duplicate rows.

Comment: Pasting just the values doesn't get rid of the problem. The cells appear empty, but a Find & Select doesn't acknowledge the cells as blank. It did find 3 duplicates, but now I still have a 3 data cell surplus.

Comment: If you paste values (including cells which evaluated as =""), and there are blank cells that Excel sees as NON-BLANK, you have 2 options: deal with this in your formulas [using OR(ISBLANK(A1),A1="")], or go to the data ribbon, and use Text to Columns. As to why you still have more lines one way or another - sort the items from each list you created from each method. Then sort your main list. Go through line by line. What items are missing?